# OpenSSL cannot verify public key file

Tags: openssl

Sory if this the wrong forum.
Similar format as https://superuser.com/questions/1527890/how-to-encrypt-a-message-by-using-a-pub-file my public key given to me by client has "ssh-rsa ..." format but I cannot encrypt anything with it or verify it. When I create a key and export the public key using OpenSSL I get the header and footer lines, no "ssh-rsa ..." prefix and every 65 characters have a CRLF, also their file has a space an email address at the end of the file. When I verify I get a "Cannot read public key from ..." and if I try to manipulate the file putting in the header using notepad++ I get:

> Could not read public key from ~\MyKey.pub
> 30390000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:crypto\store\store_result.c:151:

So am I just using the wrong software, if you can advise?

I know the obvious question ask the person that gave you it but you know how it works it goes thru  several layers and then back down the chain at client end, just wanted to see if I can get a quick answer here first.

I have found this I might have a read thru it:
https://superuser.com/questions/576506/how-to-use-ssh-rsa-public-key-to-encrypt-a-text

Comment: That format (`ssh-rsa {base64 of XDR-like data} {email or other text}` on one lline) is OpenSSH format; it is not supported by OpenSSL (even if you add fraudulent bogus and wrong headers), and OpenSSH will not use it to encrypt data. As #576506 shows, you can use OpenSSH's `ssh-keygen -e -mpkcs8` to _convert_ it to the format OpenSSL uses (although OpenSSH is wrong to _call_ this PKCS8; it isn't). And yes this is not programming or development.

Comment: Yeah I found that out myself so I now have it working https://www.czeskis.com/random/openssl-encrypt-file.html so do I delete my post now?? Well at least I have sent a sample encrypted file to the client see if they can decrypt, fingers crossed.